# Adding Multiple File Appernders to a single Application

Tags: java, logging, log4j, slf4j

How to add multiple file appenders or rolling file appenders to a single application in java  using log4j or slf4j.

such that the orders related logs are logged in one file and application related logs are logged in another file.

Thanks in Advance.

Comment: so both order related logs and application related logs will be same level? say info and you want it to be captured in different files?

Comment: What do you mean by "orders related logs" and "application related logs"?

Comment: my application has different modules such that each module has to log on separate file.

both logger should have different levels too....

Comment: got solved...Thanks for the Help Guys...

i referred here

http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3093600/multiple-files-with-log4j

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
log4j.rootLogger=DEBUG

log4j.logger.tradelog=DEBUG,tradelog
log4j.appender.tradelog = org.apache.log4j.RollingFileAppender
log4j.appender.tradelog.file=log/TradeLogger.log
log4j.appender.tradelog.append=true
log4j.appender.tradelog.Threshold =ON
log4j.appender.tradelog.MaxFileSize=2MB
log4j.appender.tradelog.MaxBackupIndex=10
log4j.appender.tradelog.layout = org.apache.log4j.PatternLayout
log4j.appender.tradelog.layout.ConversionPattern = %-5p %d [%t] %c: %m%n

log4j.logger.orderslog=DEBUG,orderslog
log4j.appender.orderslog = org.apache.log4j.RollingFileAppender
log4j.appender.orderslog.file=log/OrdersLogger.log
log4j.appender.orderslog.append=true
log4j.appender.orderslog.Threshold =ON
log4j.appender.orderslog.MaxFileSize=2MB
log4j.appender.orderslog.MaxBackupIndex=10
log4j.appender.orderslog.layout = org.apache.log4j.PatternLayout
log4j.appender.orderslog.layout.ConversionPattern = %-5p %d [%t] %c: %m%n

log4j.appender.tradelog.Threshold=WARN
log4j.appender.orderslog.Threshold=WARN`
```